# Windows 7 taskbar clock disappears

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, clock

The clock on the right of the taskbar is enabled but seems to disappear every time I reboot my computer. (I'm guessing at the frequency; I notice it has gone away every day after I dock.) The clock returns if I right-click the up arrow button for the systray icons and choose "Properties" (and do nothing, just hit Cancel). But I don't want to keep having to do this.

Obviously this is a glitch. Does anyone know of a permanent workaround?

Using a Dell Latitude E6420 laptop, a docking station, Win7 x64, 8GB RAM, dual monitors, 1920x1200 resolution per monitor.

All Windows Updates are applied.

Comment: Does it do this both on and off the dock?

Comment: Is this machine on a domain? There are group policies that will hide the clock on you.

Comment: Have you ever tried booting in safe mode. I had the same glitch and I fixed it after safe booting.

Comment: You mean just boot into safe mode, then reboot in regular mode? I obviously can't function in safe mode LOL.